# Explain Android code - getLineStart

Tags: android, layout, text

In android.text.Layout, there's a method that returns the text offset of the beginning of the specified line, called `getLineStart()`;
It is an abstract method in Layout class, here's the implementation of `StaticLayout` and `DynamicLayout` :

Static:

```
@Override
    public int getLineStart(int line) {
        return mLines[mColumns * line + START] & START_MASK;
    }
```

Dynamic:

```
 @Override
    public int getLineStart(int line) {
        return mInts.getValue(line, START) & START_MASK;
    }
```

Can anyone explain this two methods for me ? I don't know exactly how this can get the line start.

Comment: This is not a tutorial site.

Comment: @DerGolem I know this kinda question is not welcomed here, but where am I supposed to get answer for this?